# Checking if a bug was fixed

Tags: suspend, bug-reporting

How could i check if an issue was fixed with past updates ?

Actually im looking for bug related with wireless can't connect after suspend mode in Ubuntu 14.04.
At this moment i disabled all power management options to prevent it.

Comment: If your bug has been reported (by anyone), it will be marked as so. If it is not, I'm not sure.
You can try to search it on google, especially the result to the bugs.launchpad.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to find where the bug is reported in Launchpad. If it's not, [report it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

[Log in to launchpad](https://launchpad.net/+login) (in the above link you have more info about that), go to the main page of the bug, and then:

[image: launchpad bug]

1. Add yourself to the "affected-by-the-bug" list,
2. And subscribe to the mail notifications. You can decide to receive all messages, or just the changes of state (which will tell you if the bug is marked as fixed or whatever).

[image]